# How to resolve Scatter offload is not configured Error on Jumbo Frame testing in Mellanox

Tags: dpdk, mellanox

How to resolve scatter offload configuration error on testing Jumboframes in Bluefield Mellanox 2?
DPDK Version - 20.11.1

Error details:

```
Initializing rx queues on lcore 1 ... rxq=0,0,0 mlx5_pci: port 0 Rx queue 0: Scatter offload is not configured )
mlx5_pci: port 0 unable to allocate queue index 0
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: rte_eth_rx_queue_setup: err=-12,port=0*

./l3fwd-acl -l 1,2 -n 4  -- -p 0x3 --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)" --rule_ipv4="/root/rule_ipv4.db" --rule_ipv6="/root/rule_ipv6.db" --eth-dest=0,01:00:00:00:00:00 --enable-jumbo --max-pkt-len=8000
```

Edited the l3fwd-acl example for enabling jumboframe testing

```
static struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = {
        .rxmode = {
                .mq_mode        = ETH_MQ_RX_RSS,
                .max_rx_pkt_len = 9000,
                .split_hdr_size = 0,
                .offloads = DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_CHECKSUM,
        },
        .rx_adv_conf = {
                .rss_conf = {
                        .rss_key = NULL,
                        .rss_hf = ETH_RSS_IP | ETH_RSS_UDP |
                                ETH_RSS_TCP | ETH_RSS_SCTP,
                },
        },
        .txmode = {
                .mq_mode = ETH_MQ_TX_NONE,
                .offloads = (DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_CHECKSUM|DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS),

        },
};

if (!strncmp(lgopts[option_index].name,
                                        OPTION_ENBJMO, sizeof(OPTION_ENBJMO))) {
                                struct option lenopts = {
                                        "max-pkt-len",
                                        required_argument,
                                        0,
                                        0
                                };

                                printf("jumbo frame is enabled\n");

                                port_conf.rxmode.offloads |=
                                                DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_JUMBO_FRAME;
                                port_conf.txmode.offloads |=
                                                DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS;

 /*
                                 * if no max-pkt-len set, then use the
                                 * default value RTE_ETHER_MAX_LEN
                                 */
                                if (0 == getopt_long(argc, argvopt, "",
                                                &lenopts, &option_index)) {
                                        ret = parse_max_pkt_len(optarg);
                                        if ((ret < 64) ||
                                                (ret > MAX_JUMBO_PKT_LEN)) {
                                                printf("invalid packet "
                                                        "length\n");
                                                print_usage(prgname);
                                                return -1;
                                        }
                                        port_conf.rxmode.max_rx_pkt_len = ret;
                                }
                                printf("set jumbo frame max packet length "
                                        "to %u\n",
                                        (unsigned int)
                                        port_conf.rxmode.max_rx_pkt_len);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing rx mode offload to DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_SCATTER for receiving segmented mbufs and RX and Tx descriptor value to 4096